# Cramer's Rule example

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I'm reading this [site](http://www.solitaryroad.com/c634.html), and I would like to find an example of a linear system of the case 3 below with no solutions:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{cases}
0x+0y &=& 0 \\
0x+0y &=& 1
\end{cases}$$